# Group messages by key for pulsar key_shared subscription type

Tags: message-queue, apache-pulsar

Say I have an unbounded set of keys for messages published to a pulsar topic.

```
{k0, k1, ..., kn}
```

And a finite set of expected message categories, where the category information is part of the message payload.

```
{c0, c1, c2}
```

Whenever all message categories for a given key are consumed I want to invoke an action in my application. For example, if I see the following key/category pairs, I would expect to see an action invoked.

```
{(k0, c0), (k0, c1), (k0, c2)} => action invoked for key k0
{(k1, c0), (k1, c1), (k1, c2)} => action invoked for key k1
```

In order to ensure application resiliency I only ack messages once all categories have been consumed. If a message pertaining to the same category is consumed twice I can ack the older message, holding on to one message per category.

Now, let's say I have a single consumer attached to the subscription and configured with the key_shared subscription type. We consume the following key/category pairs.

```
{(k0, c0), (k0, c1)}
```

And while waiting for `(k0, c2)` a second consumer is added to the subscription. According to [this issue](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/15705), the new consumer will not receive messages until the existing consumer acks or nacks the pending messages. This seems to be expected behaviour, and is indeed the behaviour I am seeing.

I am wondering if there is there a more idiomatic way I can go about implementing this feature? Does it make sense to delay acking of messages in order to achieve this grouping behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a partitioned topic with the failover subscription type achieves our design goal. Below are a description of the approaches we explored and the observed behaviour.

**Non-partitioned topic with key_shared subscription**

When the application is scaled out (more consumers added to the subscription), any pending messages (messages delivered to a consumer, but not yet acked) cause the new consumer to not receive *any* messages until the pending messages are acked/nacked or the pre-existing consumer unsubscribes.

**Partitioned topic with failover subscription**

When the application is scaled out, topic/partition pairs are re-assigned evenly across consumers and pending messages (if any) are re-delivered. Consumers needs to be informed when ownership of a topic partition changes in order to clear the internal state, for this the [consumer event listener](https://pulsar.apache.org/api/client/2.10.x/org/apache/pulsar/client/api/ConsumerEventListener.html) can be used.